# yfinance package - python - how to download multiple prices in same currency

Tags: python

Is there a way to download stocks in a single currency on yfinance?  So if im trying to download prices on 0285.HK and 034020.KS, can I download both prices in EUR?  Thx

```
df = yf.download('0285.HK', start = startDate, end = endDate)
```

This obviously delivers a price in local currency on 0285.HK, how do I get that in EUR?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. However you can simply multiply by a constant or you can use `'HKDEUR=X'` ticker to convert daily values in EUR:

```
import yfinance as yf

startDate = '2023-1-1'
endDate = '2023-12-31'

df = yf.download('0285.HK', start=startDate, end=endDate)
cur = yf.download('HKDEUR=X', start=startDate, end=endDate)['Close']

cols = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close']
df[cols] = df[cols].mul(cur, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                Open      High       Low     Close  Adj Close    Volume
Date                                                                   
2023-01-03  2.998825  3.070797  2.914858  3.070797   3.047644   3469825
2023-01-04  3.105997  3.142395  2.917938  2.978602   2.956145  11605317
2023-01-05  2.997606  3.069983  2.961417  2.997606   2.975005   6845515
2023-01-06  3.059749  3.059749  2.938089  2.974587   2.952160   5267278
2023-01-09  2.944140  3.022250  2.932124  2.962166   2.939832   5444298
...              ...       ...       ...       ...        ...       ...
2023-11-03  4.092920  4.381832  4.092920  4.327661   4.327661  10960371
2023-11-06  4.298860  4.447712  4.298860  4.334585   4.334585   7870580
2023-11-07  4.341938  4.353866  4.198797  4.222654   4.222654   5138985
2023-11-08  4.292132  4.351911  4.196486  4.274198   4.274198   4862699
2023-11-09  4.313520  4.337484  4.199691  4.247619   4.247619   3165858

[209 rows x 6 columns]
```

Input:

```
>>> df
                 Open       High        Low      Close  Adj Close    Volume
Date                                                                       
2023-01-03  25.000000  25.600000  24.299999  25.600000  25.406988   3469825
2023-01-04  25.600000  25.900000  24.049999  24.549999  24.364902  11605317
2023-01-05  24.850000  25.450001  24.549999  24.850000  24.662642   6845515
2023-01-06  25.150000  25.150000  24.150000  24.450001  24.265657   5267278
2023-01-09  24.500000  25.150000  24.400000  24.650000  24.464149   5444298
...               ...        ...        ...        ...        ...       ...
2023-11-03  34.000000  36.400002  34.000000  35.950001  35.950001  10960371
2023-11-06  36.099998  37.349998  36.099998  36.400002  36.400002   7870580
2023-11-07  36.400002  36.500000  35.200001  35.400002  35.400002   5138985
2023-11-08  35.900002  36.400002  35.099998  35.750000  35.750000   4862699
2023-11-09  36.000000  36.200001  35.049999  35.450001  35.450001   3165858

[209 rows x 6 columns]
```

Currency converter:

```
>>> cur
Date
2023-01-02    0.119631
2023-01-03    0.119953
2023-01-04    0.121328
2023-01-05    0.120628
2023-01-06    0.121660
                ...   
2023-11-03    0.120380
2023-11-06    0.119082
2023-11-07    0.119284
2023-11-08    0.119558
2023-11-09    0.119820
Name: Close, Length: 224, dtype: float64
```